# How to make a countdown CountDown Timer in java ( stopwatch Java )

Tags: java, countdowntimer, stopwatch

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class StopWatch 
{
    public static int interval;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input seconds => : ");
        interval = input.nextInt();
        int delay = 1000;
        int period = 1000;
        Timer time = new Timer();
        System.out.println(interval);
        time.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                if (interval == 0) {
                    System.out.println("work finished");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(setInterval());
                }
            }
        }, delay, period);
    }

    private static int setInterval() {          
        return --interval;
    }    
}
```

I have a problem in this that when I run it doesn't stop from counting!

So, how do I make it stop when counter reaches 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.test;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class StopWatch 
{
    public static int interval;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input seconds => : ");
        interval = input.nextInt();
        int delay = 1000;
        int period = 1000;
        final Timer time = new Timer();
        System.out.println(interval);
        time.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                if (interval == 0) {
                    System.out.println("work finished");
                    time.cancel();
                    time.purge();
                } else {
                    System.out.println(setInterval());
                }
            }
        }, delay, period);
    }

    private static int setInterval() {

        return --interval;
    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: answers just throwing code at the reader ... are not very helpful. Neither to you (rarely upvoted) nor for the reader; as there are **zero** explanations. And you know, taking the three lines I wrote; and putting them into the original source code ... doesn't exactly make up for that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to instruct the timer to stop upon the last iteration; like:

```
public void run() {
   if (interval == 0) {
     System.out.println("work finished");
     time.cancel();
     time.purge();
```

See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel()) for further details. You probably don't the call to `purge()` here, as there is only one thread dealing with that timer; but in more "generic" use cases it would be required.

You might have to change

```
Timer time = new Timer();
```

to

```
final Timer time = new Timer();
```

(depending on your version of Java) to tell the compiler that it is save to access the outer local variable from within that anonymous inner class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick fix for your issue. You have to call the method cancel() as below:

```
public static int interval;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Input seconds => : ");
        interval = input.nextInt();
        int delay = 1000;
        int period = 1000;
        Timer time = new Timer();
        System.out.println(interval);
        time.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            public void run() {
                if (interval == 0) {
                    System.out.println("work finished");
                    time.cancel();
                } else {
                    System.out.println(setInterval());
                }
            }
        }, delay, period);
    }

    private static int setInterval() {

        return --interval;
    }

}
```

Dominique Ubersfeld

Comment: Hint: taking the two answers that are already there, pulling them together ... without providing any further insight or "added value" ... will not result in upvotes for you.